# Pycharm app keeps opening my html files and links

Tags: google-chrome, html

Issue: .html files and links and ipython notebooks seem to be all routed through pycharm.

Whenever I open a html file or start a jupyter server, it opens up with pycharm instead of chrome.

I made sure that Chrome is my default browser in settings. Tried several times this one:
when opening a html file click open with -> other -> tick always open with chrome. It works just for that file but then html files are still associated with pycharm and next time it still opens with pycharm by default.

Comment: @mmmmmm no, I already did that

Comment: Have you  used Get Info to chnage things - that is not in your question

Comment: Thanks @mmmmmm. I've missed that and it works this way.